# Servlet getParameter() returns null but the value is transmitted

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

I have a form to sign up for an event. In this form are two hidden fields for user email and event id. As you can see below.

```
<form action="EventRegister" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${events.Id}"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}">  
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Anmelden</button>
</form>
```

When I call the Servlet it fails at this lines:

```
Integer event = Integer.valueOf(request.getAttribute("id")); 
String email = request.getAttribute("email");
```

and throws exceptions. The `getParameter()` method doesn't work also. The `Integer event` throws a `NumberFormatException`, the `String email` is also null. I already tried it with just one of them, changed their names and so on. But they're still null!

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

The strange thing is, the values are transmitted. As you can see in the Developer Tools of Chrome (link at the end). I can't find any mistakes. I already using this in many servlets and it works fine.

Help me please! Probably I'm doing something completely wrong, but I can't find my mistake.

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx1K5.png)

Comment: Post your servlet class and web page

Comment: yeah... check the link, as you can see there, the values are transmitted ...

Comment: But if you have signed up, you'll get shown the sign off form. Could this cause problems? It's the same form but the SignOff Servlet is called-

Comment: Please check all the parameters at your servlet, whether they are transmitted or not, you cant be sure by checking them at your browser console.

Comment: How can I do that? :) Sorry I'm not really experienced in Web.

Comment: Use request.getParameter() and restart the server. request.getAttribute is wrong here.

Comment: I already tried the getParamter() method as I said. :(

Comment: Yes, but did you restart the server after that?

Comment: I restarted my computer (remove, clean and so on too)  ... so yes

Comment: Debug the doPost method and verify that the request contains both id and email parameters. Just because your browser seems to send them correctly does not necessarily mean the servlet has them.

Comment: I reistalled tomcat, now it works. LoL. Could you give me answer, so I can mark the question as solved and give you the best answer for your nice help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use request.getParameter("id") instead of request.getAttribute("id"). HTML form fields are retrieved with  the getParameter method.

If you're still getting null , restart the server and redeploy your application. If after doing all that you're still getting null, reinstall your web container.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved.